# Double Tap to Top

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have seen this new feature in my `Samsung Galaxy S3` called `Double Tap to Top` where on scrolling to the bottom of the `listView` the user needs not scroll back to top he just needs to Double tap on top of the phone/device and it automatically scrolls back to the top.
Is there any possibility I can do similar to that with my `custom listView` inside my application also?
I have googled but couldn't find a solution.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think you have to implement onTouchListner for your listView then check for doubleTap and call scrollToTop() method of adapter.

Comment: so how do we check the double tap on top of the device or phone?

Comment: I don't want double tap on listView or on the screen.
That is easy to do, I want double tap on the phone's body. It has something to do with motion sensors.
Check that feature on a real Samsung Galaxy S3 phone if you can, maybe you will understand what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Take hint from following code just implement it in `onListItemClick` of your `listView`

```
 setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int <a href='http://viagra365.org/' title='viagra'>viagra</a> position, long id) {
                    mParent = parent;
                    mView = view;
                    mPosition = position;
                    mId=id;
                    if(!mTookFirstEvent) //Testing if first tap occurred
                    {
                        mPositionHolder=position;
                        //this will hold the position variable from first event.
                        //In case user presses any other item (position)
                        mTookFirstEvent=true;
                        mMessage = mMessage == null? new Message() : mHandler.obtainMessage();
                        //”Recycling” the message, instead creating new instance we get the old one
                        mHandler.removeMessages(SINGLE_TAP);
                        mMessage.what = SINGLE_TAP;
                        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mMessage, DELAY);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(mPositionHolder == position)
                        {
                            mHandler.removeMessages(SINGLE_TAP);
                            //Removing the message that was queuing for scheduled
                            //sending after elapsed time > DELAY,
                            //immediately when we have second event,
                            //when the time is < DELAY
                            mPosition = position;
                            mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                            //obtaining old message instead creating new one
                            mMessage.what=DOUBLE_TAP;
                            mHandler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(mMessage);
                            //Sending the message immediately when we have second event,
                            //when the time is < DELAY
                            mTookFirstEvent=false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /* When the position is different from previously
                             * stored position in mPositionHolder (mPositionHolder!=position).
                             * Wait for double tap on the new item at position which is
                             * different from mPositionHolder. Setting the flag mTookFirstEvent
                             * back to false.
                             *
                             * However we can ignore the case when we have mPosition!=position, when we want,
                             * to do something when onSingleTap/onItemClickListener are called.
                             *
                             */
                            mMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                            mHandler.removeMessages(SINGLE_TAP);
                            mTookFirstEvent=true;
                            mMessage.what = SINGLE_TAP;
                            mPositionHolder = position;
                            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mMessage, DELAY);
                        }
                    }
            }
      });
```

For more details you can refer  https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListView or https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListViewHandler